# How to use lists properly here?

Tags: python

My issue is as follows: I want to create a program that accepts integers which are higher than 0 and lower than 21 and which are separated from one another by one space. Then I want to create a list, where prime numbers are going to be appended without any changes and non-prime numbers are going to be split in elements, which are going to be prime numbers.

**Input:** 3 6 7 12

**Output:** [3, 2, 3, 7, 2, 2, 3]

This is what Ive came up with. When I try running the programm with above-mentioned input, for 12 it only outputs 2 and 3 without another 2. What can be a problem here?

```
l_prime = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19]
l = []
disposable = None
iterate = input().split()
for i in iterate:
  a = int(i)
  for j in range (0,len(l_prime)):
    disposable = j
    if a == l_prime[j]:
      l.append(l_prime[j])
    else:
      if a % l_prime[disposable] == 0:
        l.append(l_prime[disposable])
        a = a / l_prime[disposable]
      else:
        if a <= 1:
          break
        else:
          disposable += 1
l
```

I will appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What’s outputs variables?

Comment: your code has this structure: for {for {if {} else {if {} else{ if{} else{}}}}. This is very hard to debug and needlessly complex. Sketch out a diagram of your algorithm and then try to implement it in python.

Comment: Small tip, try running your script with a debugger and follow through the steps one by one. I usually catch logical flaws this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically just have to change this `if` statement

```
if a % l_prime[disposable] == 0:
```

to a `while` loop so you can add repeated prime factors:

```
while a % l_prime[disposable] == 0:
```

But the code can be simplified further. First, you do not have to make a special case for prime numbers at all; they are just numbers that have a single prime factor. Also, you can iterate the elements of `l_prime` directly instead of using an index, and in particular that `disposable` variable has no purpose at all. Given the low number of primes to test you might even drop the `break`

```
for a in map(int, iterate):
    for p in l_prime:
        while a % p == 0:
            l.append(p)
            a //= p
```

Comment: Note that this might run in an infinite loop if `input()` includes a `0`, but according to the description it should not. If you still want to counter it, you can just add `and a > 0` to the `while`, or add a separate `if - break` to the outer loop.